# How to insert a star symbol in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, characters, star

I would need to insert black or white five -pointed stars in a tikz figure, but I don't know the computer coding of these special characters... where can I find them?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/47927

Comment: You state that you are looking for a character, but In case you need a shape (for a node) you may want to take a look at the `shapes.geometric` library that comes with Ti*k*Z.

Comment: I looked in all libraries, on Detexify, but nothing! Otherwise I wouldn't have asked the question...

Comment: Well, there is also [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](https://ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive). LaTeX, for example, has `$\star$`, but there are a lot of packages that contain filled and non-filled five-pointed starts. For example, the `MnSymbol` package provides `\filledlargestar` and `\largestar` .

Comment: Finally, if you have a font that provides both codepoints such as DejaVu Sans, you can use `\char"2605` and `\char"2606` to insert these glyphs directly. MWE (to be compiled with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX): `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{fontspec} \setmainfont{DejaVu Sans} \begin{document} \char"2605 \char"2606 \end{document}`

Comment: It is possible that some may have misunderstood your question. Are you looking for a star character, or are you trying to make a star shape in a `tikzfigure`?

Comment: @Sandy G I was looking for a star character. Ifound it in the List mentioned by Jasper Habicht